# Windbg parse variable from .foreach value

Tags: c#, windbg

Executing next command in WinDbg

```
.foreach (function_name {x /1 JittyProject!*}) {.echo function_name}
```

Result should be

```
JittyProject!ApplyAsync
....
```

Is it possible somehow parse from `function_name` in one variable `JittyProject` in another `ApplyAsync`

Comment: `!for_each_module`/[`!for_each_function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-for-each-function) looks like they would be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!for_each_function **was and is buggy**
it requires private pdbs
if you use the undocumented -f switch  to force it to use public pdbs
it will hang indefinitely until you terminate windbg

parsing a complete string from .foreach output is PITA

basically function names can and do contain spaces
.foreach considers each space to be a seperator 
so it would chop a function name into multiple tokens

and .foreach doesn't honor ctrl+c or ctrl+break or alt+delete so it will keep on spewing venom until it dies

if you can use a latest windbg i would suggest you to switch to javascript or natvis

below is an output using just dx the natvis expression evaluator

execute the command and obtain an array of results into an uservariable

```
dx @$foo = Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand("x /1 calc!*")
```

some sample members of above array (notice  the last entry below has many spaces and
   .foreach  will cut it into as many pieces  as spaces )

```
0:000> dx -r0 @$foo[4]
@$foo[4]         : calc!CContainer::ToggleHistoryFunc
0:000> dx -r0 @$foo[101]
@$foo[101]       : calc!`ATL::CAtlRECharTraitsW::GetAbbrevs'::`2'::s_szAbbrevs
0:000> dx -r0 @$foo[861]
@$foo[861]       : calc!ATL::AtlAdd<unsigned int>
0:000> dx -r0 @$foo[1684]
@$foo[1684]      : calc!ATL::CAtlMap<ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,ATL::StrTraitATL<unsigned short,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > *,FORMULA_DEFINTION *,MyCStringPtrTrait,ATL::CElementTraits<FORMULA_DEFINTION *> >::GetKeyAt
```

there are 2925 or 0xb6d functions in the array

```
0:000> dx @$foo.Count(),x; dx @$foo.Count(),d
@$foo.Count(),x  : 0xb6d
@$foo.Count(),d  : 2925



0:000> dx -r0 @$foo[2925]
Error: <Unable to get error code text> (0x8000000b) <<< out of bounds
0:000> dx -r0 @$foo[2924]
@$foo[2924]      : calc!Gdiplus::Image::`vector deleting destructor'
```

now that you have an array you can grab the substrings of each by using the ! as seperator

```
0:000> dx -r1 @$foo.Select(p=> new{ Module = p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf("!")), FName = p.Substring(p.IndexOf("!")) })[2924]
@$foo.Select(p=> new{ Module = p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf("!")), FName = p.Substring(p.IndexOf("!")) })[2924]                
    Module           : calc
    FName            : !Gdiplus::Image::`vector deleting destructor'


0:000> dx -r1 @$foo.Select(p=> new{ Module = p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf("!")), FName = p.Substring(p.IndexOf("!")) })[864]
@$foo.Select(p=> new{ Module = p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf("!")), FName = p.Substring(p.IndexOf("!")) })[864]                
    Module           : calc
    FName            : !_real


0:000> dx -r1 @$foo.Select(p=> new{ Module = p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf("!")), FName = p.Substring(p.IndexOf("!")) })[1684]
@$foo.Select(p=> new{ Module = p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf("!")), FName = p.Substring(p.IndexOf("!")) })[1684]                
    Module           : calc
    FName            : !ATL::CAtlMap<ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,ATL::StrTraitATL<unsigned short,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > *,FORMULA_DEFINTION *,MyCStringPtrTrait,ATL::CElementTraits<FORMULA_DEFINTION *> >::GetKeyAt
```

or getting all function names from all loaded modules

```
0:000> dx @$foo = Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand("x /1 *!*")
0:000> dx @$foo.Count()
@$foo.Count()    : 0x1d4b9
0:000> dx -r1 @$foo.Select(p=> new{ Module = p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf("!")), FName = p.Substring(p.IndexOf("!")+1) })[15084]
    Module           : COMCTL32
    FName            : CCalendar::_DateSetMax
```

the modules that are this huge array of 11993 functions

```
0:000> dx -r1 @$foo.Select(p=>p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf("!"))).Distinct()
@$foo.Select(p=>p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf("!"))).Distinct()                
    [0x0]            : SharedUserData
    [0x1]            : calc
    [0x2]            : WINMM
    [0x3]            : gdiplus
    [0x4]            : UxTheme
    [0x5]            : COMCTL32
    [0x6]            : VERSION
    [0x7]            : KERNELBASE
    [0x8]            : msvcrt
    [0x9]            : GDI32
    [0xa]            : USER32
    [0xb]            : LPK
    [0xc]            : OLEAUT32
    [0xd]            : ADVAPI32
    [0xe]            : SHLWAPI
    [0xf]            : USP10
    [0x10]           : SHELL32
    [0x11]           : RPCRT4
    [0x12]           : kernel32
    [0x13]           : ole32
    [0x14]           : ntdll
    [0x15]           : sechost
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like `dx -r1 @$foo.Select(p=> new{ Module = p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf("!")), FName = p.Substring(p.IndexOf("!")) }).ToList().ForEach(x=> Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand("!mbm "+x.Module +"!*" +x.FName))` somehow. It seems that LINQ in NatVis do not have ToList,ForEach extension functions.

Comment: it appears you are running in loops first splitting and then joining again may i know what you are trying to do  i am not well versed with .net sos etc but may be there is a better workaround with native windbg methods and awk grep sed